# Does ruby call initialize method automatically?

Tags: ruby

Do I need to explicitly initialize an object if an initialize method is included in class definition?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, Ruby does not call `initialize` automatically.

The default implementation of `Class#new` looks a bit like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```

[Actually, `initialize` is `private` by default so you need to use `obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)`.]

So, the default implementation of `Class#new` *does* call `initialize`, but it would be perfectly possible (albeit extremely stupid) to override or overwrite it with an implementation that does not.

So, it's not *Ruby* that calls `initialize`, it's `Class#new`. You may think that's splitting hairs, because `Class#new` is an integral part of Ruby, but the important thing here is: it's not some kind of language magic. It's a method like any other, and like any other method it can be overridden or overwritten to do something completely different.

And, of course, if you don't use `new` to create an object but instead do it manually with `allocate`, then `initialize` wouldn't be called either.

There *are* some cases where objects are created without calling `initialize`. E.g. when `dup`ing or `clone`ing, `initialize_dup` and `initialize_clone` are called instead of `initialize` (both of which, in turn, call `initialize_copy`). And when deserializing an object via, say, `Marshal`, its internal state is reconstructed directly (i.e. the instance variables are set reflectively) instead of through `initialize`.

Comment: Do you want to mention how a derived class interacts with its parent's `initialize`?

Comment: @Jorge what do you mean by `overwrite`? can you bit clarify this?

Comment: @Priti: Ruby has so-called *open classes*, it allows you to overwrite an existing method with a new implementation.

Comment: @WayneConrad: my point is that `initialize` is nothing special, it's just a method like any other. So, `super` works exactly the same as it always does.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ohh!yes it is like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called from `new` method, which you use to create objects.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "explicit". Usually you need to, even if there are no arguments:

```
object = MyClass.new(...)
```

In some cases there are factory methods that produce instances you can use, creating a form of implicit initialization:

```
object = MyClass.factory_method(...)
```

This would have the effect of calling `MyObject.new` internally.

There are some libraries which have rather unusual method signatures, like:

```
object = MyClass(...)
object = MyClass[...]
```

The effect is the same, as these might look odd but are just method calls.