# How does Ruby make #initialize private?

Tags: ruby, private

I understand that Ruby's [#initialize method is private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245315/does-ruby-call-initialize-method-automatically). However, what stumps me is *how* Ruby makes the method private.

We normally define classes like this:

```
class Cat
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def say_name
    puts @name
  end
end
```

where `#initialize` seems to be defined publicly alongside `#say_name`. How does Ruby manage to make `#initialize` private after the class definition?

Comment: Surely that's just how OOP works?

Comment: What's being asked is why the `initialize` method is special. It hasn't been declared as private.

Comment: Yup, exactly what tadman said!

Answer (score 11):

[Yukihiro Matsumoto (the inventor of Ruby) has said](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/171982#754062):

> #initialize is, by its design, supposed to be called only from within #new to separate per object/class initialization from the #new, thus you don't have to redefine #new.  When you need/want to redefine #new, it's a sign of a bad design, I believe.
>
> One of the reason #initialize being private is to tell you bad design.

So in summary it's a built in feature of Ruby that #initialize is automatically private and it's so developers won't easily call it outside of the `.new` class method.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering _how_ is `#initialize` made private after we define it. When we finish the class definition, is there something happening in the background that privatizes `#initialize`, even though we've defined it publicly? Or is it just some magic that happens in C land?

Comment: It's Ruby. #initialize is a special keyword to Ruby and when it encounters it, it will ensure it's considered private.

Answer (score 6):

Very interesting question! I researched it and found some interesting things about Ruby, though I did not find the exact answer you're looking for.

`initialize` is a private instance method that is meant to be redefined on most objects. It comes from `BasicObject`, the Ruby class from which all objects and classes inherit.

Any new class you create in Ruby will have a private instance method called `initialize`:

```
class Q ; end
Q.private_instance_methods.include?(:initialize)
=> true
```

That instance method is inherited from `BasicObject#initialize`:

```
q = Q.new
q.method(:initialize)
=> #<Method: Q(BasicObject)#initialize>
```

And the method itself is not defined in Ruby, it comes from the C source of the language:

```
q.method(:initialize).source_location
=> nil
```

This is what that [looks like](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/32674b167bddc0d737c38f84722986b0f228b44b/object.c#L3384) in the Ruby source code (`object.c` file):

```
rb_define_private_method(rb_cBasicObject, "initialize", rb_obj_dummy, 0);
```

`rb_obj_dummy` is basically a [no-op function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/32674b167bddc0d737c38f84722986b0f228b44b/object.c#L924-L928). Which makes sense because the expectation is that you'll override `initialize` with your own implementation code in your class.

All that said, your original question was about why initialize doesn't become a public method when you define it in the public space in your class definition. I don't know. Normally if you do that for any other method it will become a public method:

```
class Q
  private
  def my_private_method() "private" end
end

Q.new.my_private_method
NoMethodError: private method `my_private_method' called for #<Q:0x007fc5ea39eab0>

class Q
  def my_private_method() "now i'm a public method" end
end

Q.new.my_private_method
=> "now i'm a public method"
```

So I guess somewhere else deep in the source code defining a method named "initialize" is handled differently from other methods. I couldn't find it, but maybe someone else can.