# array push pop in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is my main code. I am using rspec

```
require_relative "rpn_calculator"
describe RPNCalculator do
let(:calculator) {RPNCalculator.new}

it "adds two numbers" do
    calculator.push(1)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.plus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq 4
end
```

And this is my code in rpn_calculator

```
class RPNCalculator
@arr=[]
@ans=0
def push(val)
    @arr.push(val)
end
def plus
    while @arr.size>=1 do
        @ans=@ans+@arr.pop
    end
end
def value
    return @ans
end
end
```

And this is the error I am getting

RPNCalculator adds two numbers
 Failure/Error: calculator.push(1)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass
 # ./rpn_calculator.rb:5:in`push'
 # ./spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in '

But I think Push is a method for arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those variables needs to be in `initialize` method:

```
class RPNCalculator
  def initialize
    @arr=[]
    @ans=0    
  end

  def push(val)
    @arr.push(val)
  end

  def plus
    while @arr.size>=1 do
      @ans=@ans+@arr.pop
    end
  end

  def value
    return @ans
  end
end
```

**Explanation:** `initialize` is private by default and is called as `obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)` in `Class#new` method's implementation. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16247013/645886) for more information.

So, when you define an `initialize` method in your class to override or overwrite its implementation according to yours. Ruby will invoke and run your defined version of `initialize` method instead. Since, `initialize` is an instance method, whatever variables(variables with `@`) you have defined, will also be shared/accessible in other instance methods, in this case: `@arr`, and `@ans`. In your case they are class variables and not instance variables, and that's why `@arr` is `nil` in `push` instance method and `@arr` in `plus` instance method.

It would be perfectly fine if you do not want to put those variables in `initialize` and instead write them in your own defined method, let's call it `initialize_variables`:

```
class RPNCalculator
  def initialize_variables
    @arr=[]
    @ans=0    
  end

  ....
  ..
end
```

It's just that now you have to always call `initialize_variables` after initializing the class object. Which is an extra overhead in your code, and not considered as a good practice. Hence use `initialize` method instead.

Comment: Oh thanx this worked :).But can you tell me why they need to be in the initialize method?

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter : I added the explanation for more clarification why `initialize` method is needed.

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter as for what happens when you define those variables outside of `initialize` (or any method definition), they are defined on the object that is currently `self` - the class `RPNCalculator` - rather than *instances* of the class.