# What is the flow? What is `initialize` doing?

Tags: ruby

I picked up from tutorials that I need to use `initialize`. Here's a portion of the code:

```
class Temperature
  def initialize(c: nil, f: nil)
    @fahrenheit = f
    @celsius = c
  end
  def in_celsius
    @celsius ||= (@fahrenheit - 32) * 5.0 / 9
  end
end
```

Here's rspec test:

```
describe "in degrees celsius" do
  it "at 50 degrees" do
    Temperature.new(:c => 50).in_celsius.should == 50
  end
```

When it tests the chunk above, value `50` is attached to key `:c`. Does `@celsius = c` mean that `c` is the value of the `:c` key? Does the `new` method automatically direct to `initialize` method?

Comment: You have two completely unrelated questions here, one is about `initialize` (which has already been asked and answered many times here on StackOverflow, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16247013/2988 ), and one is about keyword arguments. If you have two questions, you should ask two questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby `.new` creates a new object and calls the `.initialize` method on the object. If there is no initialize method declared it calls the initializer on the superclass.

So when you call `Temperature.new(c: 15)` it will pass the arguments to the initialize method:

```
def initialize(c: nil, f: nil)
  # Arguments in here are passed from .new
  @fahrenheit = f # alters the temperature instance
  @celsius = c # alters the temperature instance
  puts self.inspect # will show you that self is the new Temperature instance
end
```

**On a side note:**

Its not `@intialize` since the at sign denotes an *instance variable*. `initialize` is a method. When writing about methods the convention is to write `Foo#bar` for instance methods and `Foo.bar` for class methods.