# Is there a way to tell if `method_missing` was explicitly called?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

From within the method definition, is there a way to tell if the method `method_missing` was explicitly called or was called as a hook method?

With the method `initialize`, it is possible to tell if it was called explicitly or was called as a hook by doing the following:

```
class A
  def initialize
    puts caller
  end
end
```

When called as a hook, the method `initialize` has a line with `new`:

```
a = A.new
# => ...:in `new'
# => ...
# => ...:in `<main>'
```

When called explicitly, it does not have such line (unless it is explicitly called from `new`):

```
a.send(:initialize)
# => ...
# => ...:in `<main>'
```

But when I do a similar thing with `method_missing`, I cannot distinguish the two cases:

```
class A
  def method_missing *;
    puts caller
  end
end

a.foo
# => ...
# => ...:in `<main>'

a.method_missing
# => ...
# => ...:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why would one want to call `method_missing` directly? And why do you want to identify that case?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What is wrong with asking it? Do all questions have to have a practical use? You don't allow purely logical/theoretical questions? If that is the case, then there are many many questions on this site that have to be criticized.

Comment: @Sergio, Sergio, Sergio. Such questions are merely to exercise the little grey cells. We must keep fit!

Comment: @sawa: I'm just being curious :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: my bad :)

Comment: I actually do have a (potentially/in principle) practical use, and so do my other previous questions over the years that may have seemed unpractical. It might become clearer when I publicize my work.

Comment: You've piqued our curiosity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `initialize`, which [is invoked explicitly via the `Class#new`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16247013/794242), the [`BasicObject#method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) is invoked by the Ruby interpreter:

> Invoked by Ruby when obj is sent a message it cannot handle. symbol is
>   the symbol for the method called, and args are any arguments that were
>   passed to it. By default, the **interpreter raises an error** when this
>   method is called. However, it is possible to override the method to
>   provide more dynamic behavior.

[`Kernel#caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) will not include those locations in the execution stack trace from where Ruby interpreter invoked the `method_missing` if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but "`Kernel#caller` will not include those locations" is exactly what I showed in the question. I was implying whether there is a different way. If your answer is negative on that, then that alone can be a good answer, provided the arguments that lead to that conclusion is described.

Comment: @sawa Yeah - I don't have proof yet as to it is not possible - still looking up stuff, but no luck yet.  So far all I have noticed is that only code that are called explicitly is shown in `caller`.  `method_missing` is like a default `rescue` for `NoMethodError`.

Comment: That can actually be a hint toward doing it if it is true.

Comment: And it turned out that that was not correct. Defining  `def method_missing *; check_if_called_explicitly; end; def check_if_called_explicitly; puts caller; end` shows the `method_missing` line even if it is called implicitly.

Comment: @sawa That's not any different from if you had called `puts caller(0)` in your original code.  I used `TracePoint`, there is no difference in two sequences as far as call trace is concerned.  Looks like its not possible to figure out the difference by using `caller` or equivalent code

Comment: Okay, thanks. I suppose it is impossible for general cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the first argument:

```
class A
  def method_missing(name = nil, *)
    if name
      puts "called via `#{name}'"
    else
      puts "called directly"
    end
  end
end

A.new.foo
#=> called via `foo'

A.new.method_missing
#=> called directly
```

Comment: By the way, I too thought about it, but when you do `A.new.method_missing :foo`, you will not be able to distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: That would be a partial answer for my particular example. But what if I called it explicitly with an argument?